# Accessing field of one field from another?

Tags: java

Like say I had two classes, `Class1` and `Class2`, and I want to make an `if` statement in `Class2` using a field (example:`int option`) from `Class1`.

I tried creating an object:

`Class1 object = new Class1();`

in `Class2`, then writing the `if` statement:

```
if(object.option == 2)
```

But it didn't work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class2 obj = new Class2();
        int option;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an option of 1, 2 or 3");
        option = input.nextInt();
        obj.input();
    }
}

public class Class2 {

    public void input(){
        Class1 object = new Class1();
        if(object.option == 1){
            System.out.print("You've selected the option 1");
        }
        else if(object.option == 2){

            System.out.print("You've selected the option 2");
        }
        else if (object.option == 3){
            System.out.println("You've selected the option 3");
        }
    }
}
```

I get a compilation error: *option cannot be resolved to a field*

Comment: `but it didn't work.` what do you mean ?. does it not compile ??

Comment: I think we need to see the code that didn't work.

Comment: Is `Class1.option` private or public?

Comment: Is `option` a private variable?

Comment: You might want to post a bit of code here :)

Comment: If `option` is `private`, then you'll have to use a getter.

Comment: **Read the error message**.

Comment: wow.. the question is just asked 4 mins ago and there are people desperate to answer it. The strangest part is the question poster does not know how fast SO is!

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `option` within the `main()` method for `Class1`, which means it won't exist outside of that method. You need to declare it within the class but outside of any method. Also, since you're accessing it from another class, it needs to be `public` (actually not necessary since I see now both classes are in the same package) (but see the answer by [lpaloub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252984/1735262)). For this particular topic, read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html.

However, your code still isn't going to work the way you intend it to. When you come across those problems, we might be able to you. In the meantime you should study http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

In Class1 you have to declare your int as public, but that's not the best way anyway.

The best way is creating a get class in Class1 that returns the int:

`public int get(){
return (your int);
}`

And then in Class2 you call it like object.get()

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `option` field in `Class1` has the right access modifier. For example, if it's private, you won't be able to use it outside of the class. Setting the field to `public` should do the job. Sadly, without any additional details, I cannot give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method in Class2 that compares values

```
 public class Class2 {
     int willBeCompared = 2;

     public boolean compareToAnotherNumber(int option) {
        return option == willBeCompared;
     }
 }
```

It would be used like this:

```
 Class1 object = new Class1();
 Class2 comparer = new Class2();

 system.out.println(comparer.compareToAnotherNumber(object.option));
```